# VB: Want to test for mouse click events on multiple objects in a panel

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, object

I have set up a grid that generates 72 picture box's using a custom class. I need to now check if the user is clicking on any of these objects.

Picturebox class:

```
Public Class Tile
    Inherits PictureBox
    Public Side As Char
    Public Spawnable As Boolean
    Public Inhabiter As Integer = 000
    Public Sub New(ByVal LeftValue As Integer, ByVal TopValue As Integer)
        With Me
            .Size = New Size(70, 70)
            .BringToFront()
            .Top = TopValue
            .Left = LeftValue
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is were the grid is made

```
Sub SetBoard()
    Dim HorizontalCounter, VerticalCounter, TopValue, LeftValue As Integer
    TopValue = 90
    LeftValue = 275
    Do Until VerticalCounter = 6
        Do Until HorizontalCounter = 12
            Dim BoardTile As New Tile(LeftValue, TopValue)
            Tiles.Add(BoardTile)
            Controls.Add(BoardTile)
            Map.Controls.Add(BoardTile)
            LeftValue += 80
            HorizontalCounter += 1
            'If LeftValue < 800 Then BoardTile.Side = "R" Else BoardTile.Side = "B"
            'If LeftValue < 550 Or LeftValue > 1000 Then BoardTile.Spawnable = True Else BoardTile.Spawnable = False
            BoardTile.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            'If BoardTile.Side = "R" Then BoardTile.BackColor = Color.Red Else BoardTile.BackColor = Color.Blue
            'If BoardTile.Spawnable = True Then BoardTile.BackColor = Color.Green
        Loop
        LeftValue = 275
        HorizontalCounter = 0
        TopValue += 80
        VerticalCounter += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the "grid"?  Lines you drew or a number of controls?  Not a lot to go on

Comment: `AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Click`.  Create the `Private Sub pb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` method, use the `sender` parameter to determine which box was clicked.

Comment: its just a set of picture boxes set out in a grid formaton

Comment: Try Lars's method, he's got your solution. @LarsTech you should make it an answer. :)

Comment: Can someone expand on Lars comment? I get the concept of it but how do I apply it to my code.

Comment: ill put the code in the main question

Comment: is there anymore code you want me to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the method that will handle the click event:

```
Private Sub BoardTile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim t As Tile = CType(sender, Tile)
  MessageBox.Show(t.Name)
End Sub
```

Then when you create the controls, wire up the event:

```
Dim BoardTile As New Tile(LeftValue, TopValue)
BoardTile.Name = LeftValue.ToString() & " - " & TopValue.ToString()
AddHandler BoardTile.Click, AddressOf BoardTile_Click
```